# Is data extension 'ODBC' can be used under SQL Server Web Edittion?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, reporting-services, odbc

When i created a MySQL report and push it to windows server which installed with sql server web edition, i get the following error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ODBC' that is either
>   not registered for this report server or is not supported in this
>   edition of Reporting Services. (rsDataExtensionNotFound)

The question is if ODBC data extension is supported by this version of sql server (web) and if so
how can i install it on the server,
i already download the driver and installed it on my server

[image: the installed driver]

Comment: I think you need to implement or configure the data processing extension for that, which can be done in the report server configuration. Did you check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152934.aspx) link? [This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159219.aspx#ODBC) one also might help.

Comment: i don't think i need to implement anything, the driver exist i download it and installed it. on the server itself i can run the report and it's working but when i deploy it from my machine to the server it doesn't work

Comment: I have the exact same issue. My report works fine within SQL Server Data tools but can't be deployed. I get the exact same error.